# The type or namespace name 'GroundTruth' does not exist in the namespace 'Osi3' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, grpc, osi

I tried building the .cs files from the .proto via grpc.. but the file contains many errors which i am unable to resolve.

.proto file is

```
syntax = "proto3";


import "osi_groundtruth.proto";

package osi3;
service Groundtruthdata {
  // rpc ProcessGroundTruth(trial) returns(Empty) {}
   rpc ProcessGroundTruth(GroundTruth) returns(Empty){}
   rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}
//message trial{
//  GroundTruth gt = 1;
//}

message Empty {
  string result = 1;
}
// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

and the errors generated are
[C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAF9h.jpg)
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaeSj.jpg)

Comment: are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: well i dont know if i am.. as in i used this .proto to compile the python version. but with c# i am having problems. and in case i am.. i dont know how to fix them

Comment: Well its solved. i added all the .cs files to the project and was working fine..